# Remote command execution from command line in Windows XP

Tags: windows, command-line, remote-access

I have two machines (both windows xp): a Server S and a Client C. I also have the server username (SU), server password (PS) and Server IP (SIP). Suppose I know a process ID (SPID) running on the server.

Please from the client, How can I kill that process on the server ? 
Running something like the following:

client > **target= SPID , target name= SU, target password= PS , command= taskkill /PID SPID**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do that via Windows Scripting Host (WSH) which supported remote execution. See [Setting up Remote WSH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h976cd1t%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). The article contains a link to examples. (You may need to use the [WshShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a74hyyw0%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) object to invoke taskkill from your remote script.)